# How can I select the element under a given element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following problem: I have a HTML content which I'm not allowed to change, I can only use jQuery. If I click on a h1 tag, I should display the tag with a given class (current) and slide down the content. How can I select the content under the h1 tag? This is my current solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("div").hide();
    $("h1").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $(this).("div").slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But there is the problem. How can I know which h1 tag it is? Here is the HTML-Text:

```
<h1 class="bar">Überschrift 1</h1>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
<h1 class="bar">Überschrift 2</h1>
<div class="content">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: try this `$(this).next().slideDown().addClass('current')`

Comment: Thank you! It works! I wasn't aware of this function!

Comment: Glad it helps, please accept the answer then you can

Comment: Sure, in 11 minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).next().slideDown().addClass('current');
```

`.next()` gives you the next element, then you can chain the `.addClass('current')` onto the end of it